# Unhappy with wedding videography production - want expert opinions to provide an independant view

Tags: video-recording, post-production, color-correction

I recently got married and i'm very unhappy with the finally product by the videography firm who basically feel the case is closed.

I am looking to take these to court but want some additional videography experts that can provide a 'second view' that is independant and free of prejudice.

I am based in England, UK - can someone recognise some offical professional videography guilds or societies that can assist with this?

I essentially want them to view the video (from a professional aspect) and give me a detailed description of problems/defects with both post & pre video production. The video's in total are approx 90 minutes long, any advice on the matter would be appreciated.

I could add the video here but as it will likely go to court i'd want to have the video hosted privately (and not here for the whole world to see)

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be a hard one. I am a wedding videographer myself and there isn't really a guild or similar (well there is kind of but there are no requirement to be joined to one in the UK).

Now this is the awkward bit. I am going to assume that you hired this company based on their previous work and that you were happy with how it was filmed, edited and sold to you via phone, email, website, in person, etc AND you have raised the issues with them and tried to get it resolved with them first.

Now assuming the above and the company has filmed your wedding and produced a product that meets the spec provided in your contract with them, it might be hard to take them to court, if they have not produced to the spec described in any of the communications with you and or contract that might have some options within to raise a complaint.

What is actually the problem with the video, is it not like ones on their website or what has been described to you? would you be willing to upload it to the likes of Vimeo and make it a private video for someone to look at?

they would need to know exactly what you are not happy with and or where to look for issues.

Also you might find in the contract there is a statement advising that the creative control with editing is down to the company and not the client or something similar.

I hope some of that helps

Comment: Hi Adam - the problems are actually too many list... my appendix of issues is too huge for these comments.... it is an example of someone not putting any effort into their work, i have gone through their finished video and even put the exact timestamp of each issue to make it easier for them, yet the videographers do not actually respond in relation to any of it.

I've had one videographer expert review this and even they state it is well below the standard he would expect (this was an independent review of someone with 20yrs experience)